# DataTables with yadcf plugin - how to override sent parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, yadcf

I'm using DataTable with yadcf plugin and I want to override send parameters to match my API on server.

For example: I have column Order, it's third column in `columns` array and I want to send parameter called `orderSearch` instead of `columns[2].search.value`.

How can I do this? How can I manipulate parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option to manipulate parameters sent to the server.

For example:

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": {
    "url": "/script.php",
    "data": function(d){
        d.orderSearch = d.columns[2].search.value;
    }
  }
});
```

Also you can construct and return your own object which will not be merged with default DataTables response object. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/hbem11sw/1/) for demonstration.

Comment: But how can I prevent sending parameters from DataTables and only send my custom parameters ? Because on the site I see only the ability to add data, not to prevent sending default parameters from DataTables. Can you show example code ? Thanks !

Comment: @Bardr, please read the documentation referenced, especially about using [`function`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data#function) as option value. You can construct and return your own object which will not be merged with default DataTables response object. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/hbem11sw/1/) for demonstration.